# Get all selected items of a Multi Select Dropdown on form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a long form that initially populates the Multi Select Dropdown with values from the database. After this happens the user then has the option to add or remove the selected items from the dropdown. But every time the submit it and it goes to the next page, it always keeps the original array and nothing changes.

```
function getGrade($id, $grades_array)
{
        $counter = 0;
        $sql = "Select grade FROM grades";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        echo '<select name="grade" multiple="multiple" id="grades_selected">';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                if ($row['grade'] != $grades_array[$counter]) {
                        echo "<option>" . $row['grade'] . "</option>";
                } else {
                        echo "<option selected=" . $row['grade']  . ">" . $row['grade'] . "</option>";
                        $counter = $counter + 1;
                }
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        echo '</select>';
}
```

All I need it to do is right when the submit button is pressed it needs to get all of the selected values from the dropdown and create a new array with all of those values.

Comment: You want to get them in the client?

Comment: serialize the form item, post it, print out the values in a script tag with php as a js variable. Or save to localstorage (easier)

Comment: Why not just get them from a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable?

Comment: I am pretty new to all of this but my best way to explain it is that the multiselect gets populated from a database table and the selected values get populated from another table. Then the user can add or remove any options they want but when they hit the submit button the php is already done and I cant find a way for it to check the multiselect one more time to check if there are any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) to implement this. This will enable you to save the array values as a string within the browser session.

Alternatively, you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) too, but this would save the values across sessions (in multiple tabs) which is probably not what you would want for such a scenario.

Comment: Do you think there is anyway you could show me a little example?

Comment: [Here is a quick JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYVLA/) I created to show the concept. Enter a string in the input text field, then click 'Set Data'. Then refresh the page and click 'Get Data'. You will still get the data you entered before the refresh since it was saved in the browser's storage. You can view the values stored in this storage using the dev tools of your favorite browser.

Comment: [Here is another JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYVLA/2/) which gets the values of the selected items when you click `submit` and saves them in the browser using `sessionStorage`. Once you click the `Create Array` button, it gets the data from the sessionStorage and displays it. Notice how the value of the last clicked submit remains even if you refresh the browser after clicking `submit`. This is similar to going to the next page after submitting.